# How to populate DropDownList with an IEnumerable returned from GET method in Api Controller?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am new to web apps in MVC. The past 2 days I have researched and tried many things, but none applied to me; I am using an ApiController, not a Controller, so I cannot do things like "return View(model)".

If you can help me understand how to link these things together or show where my problem is that would be VERY appreciated!

**Situation:** 
I want to make a web app that has cascading drop down lists; first list for selecting car makes, and second list that shows the car models for the selected make. The lists and a submit button will be within an AJAX form.

**Question:**
I just want to know, how can I populate the first drop down list *on page load*, using a GET method in my ApiController that returns an IEnumerable of car makes?
Then I can go from there. Keep in mind that later I will have a second drop down list that populates/updates based on the first, so I want the population of the drop down lists to be done client-side.

**What I tried:**

1. Using HTML.DropDownListFor to create a list, but
   HTML.DropDownListFor always get "Object reference not set to an
   instance of an object". I also use Ajax.BeginForm, but not sure if that can 
   actually call the GET method that returns an IEnumerable and add it to the 
   list.
2. Using $(document).ready() to use a getJSON to GET the car makes from my
   ApiController method, but the getJSON would not fire.

I probably have something hugely wrong somewhere, since I cannot get anything to populate my list, and I am still learning. Thank you SO much for any help! I will now show my code, and some alternative code I tried after.

---

First are my Model classes:

```
    public class Make
    {
        public int MakeId { get; set; }
        public string MakeName { get; set; }
    }

    public class Model
    {
        public int ModelId { get; set; }
        public string ModelName { get; set; }
        public int MakeId { get; set; }
    }

    public class MakeViewModel
    {
        public int SelectedMakeId { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Make> MakesList { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is my Vehicle ApiController with two GET methods, Makes() and Models(int makeID), each returns IEnumerable. They will eventually consume from a local xml, but right now for simplicity I removed it and each just returns a List of one Make or Model item.

```
public class VehicleController : ApiController
{
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Make> Makes()
    {
        List<Make> makesList = new List<Make>();

        //Code for consuming from xml file will go here

        //For now, add one test make to the list
        Make maketest = new Make();
        maketest.MakeId = 1;
        maketest.MakeName = "MakeTest";
        makesList.Add(maketest);

        //return List of the one test make
        return makesList;
    }

    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Model> Models(int id)
    {
        List<Model> modelsList = new List<Model>();

        //Code for consuming from xml file will go here

        //For now, add one test model to the list
        Model modeltest = new Model();
        modeltest.ModelId = 1;
        modeltest.ModelName = "ModelTest";
        modeltest.MakeId = 1;
        modelsList.Add(modeltest);

        //return List of the one test model
        return modelsList;
    }
}
```

This is my Index.cshtml, which loads a partial view _Form.cshtml

```
<h2>Vehicle Selector</h2>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    @Html.Partial("_Form");
}
```

Finally is my partial view _Form.cshtml; I will show just the first half of the file for the first drop down list.
At the top, I include the model MakeViewModel which is where we can find our list of car makes..

```
@model VehicleMVC.Models.MakeViewModel
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js")" 
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" 
    type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I use Ajax.BeginForm() to call the GET method Makes() from my VehicleController to update my makes_DDL, because I want the list to be populated when page is loaded. Honestly the problem might be here, as I'm not confident it's right.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Makes", "Vehicle", new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "GET",
        UpdateTargetId = "makes_DDL"
    }))
```

I use Html.DropDownListFor() to create the makes_DDL list, though it always gives me "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedMakeId,
    (SelectList)Model.MakesList, new { @class = "makes_DDL" })
```

Thank you so much in advance!

---

**Some things I tried:**
I tried using new SelectList, but no luck:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedMakeId, new 
    SelectList(Model.MakesList, "MakeId", "MakeName"))
```

Then I tried to hardcode a test list of makes, but same "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedMakeId,
    new SelectList( new List<VehicleMVC.Models.Make>
    {
        new VehicleMVC.Models.Make { MakeId = 0, MakeName = "SmallCar"},
        new VehicleMVC.Models.Make { MakeId = 1, MakeName = "BigCar"}
    },
    "value", "text", 0), new { @class = "makes_DDL" })
```

Since I was pretty sure that the Ajax.BeginForm was not doing what I want (calling GET Makes() method from my VehicleController to populate the makes_DDL list), I tried to use $(document).ready() to use a getJSON to use the route "api/vehicle" which should call Makes(), but it seems to not fire the getJSON since the alert I put inside doesn't fire.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getMakes() {
        $.getJSON("api/vehicle",
            function (data) {
                //This alert doesn't fire, so it seems getJSON is not firing?             
                 window.alert(1);
                //Code would later go here for appending the makes from the 
                  returned IEnumerable to the makes_DDL list
            });
    }

$(document).ready(getMakes);
</script>
```

Comment: Why can't you populate the content for your first dropdown in your MVC action method which render your view ? You are getting the null reference exception because `Model.MakesList` might be null. or `Model` might be null. You have not shared how your GET action looks like.

Comment: Suggest you look at the code in [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym) - its for MVC but should give you the basic outline

Comment: Shoot, I think you're right. I just realized I don't seem to have anything that actually puts the makes into the MakesList in my MakesViewModel. I remember other people using Controller classes and not ApiController  seemed to do something like "return View(obj)".

Could you elaborate a little more on how I would store the IEnumerable of car makes that is returned from the method in my VehicleController into my Model (The MakesList in my MakeViewModel class)? I am confused because it seems I am not supposed to use things like ActionResult Index().

Thank you for replying!

Comment: Thank you so much Stephen, this seems very helpful! I will play around with this and study it for now.

So it seems like I can't use getJSON with a GET method that returns IEnumerable, I thought that it would automatically convert or something but I guess I should add some GET JsonResult methods in my VehicleController.

One thing I'm confused by and had trouble finding online, is since I'm using ApiController and not Controller, it seems I can't use "return View(model);" like the ActionResult Index() does in your Fiddle. Is there a simple equivalent to sending data to store in my Model?

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Question: Your Fiddle uses JsonResult methods so that getJSON can call them and populate the lists, but I am supposed to use IEnumerable methods. Could you describe how I would send the IEnumerable data to the View so I can populate the lists?
I assumed I could use getJSON with my methods and that the IEnumerables would be auto converted to JSON but guess I'm wrong. 
In my attempt, I used

    $.getJSON("api/vehicle", function (data) { //Code here}) to try to call the IEnumerable method and add the car makes to the drop down list, but getJSON would not fire.

Comment: Essentially as you doing now - using `public IEnumerable<Model> Models(int id)` (but you may need to configure your app to return json rather than xml by default - refer [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35937118/build-json-response-in-web-api-controller) for an example)

Comment: Thank you so much for the replies! Mine is already configured to return JSON. I guess I'm generally on the right track then, I was worried I had it all wrong but I'm starting to understand it now. The Fiddle is really useful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `@Html.DropDownListFor` you can use  `<select>` tag as follows,

```
 <select id="SelectedMakeId" name="SelectedMakeId"></select>
```

Then you can populate it with `getJson` as

```
 $(document).ready(function (e) {
     $.getJSON("http://localhost:2390/api/vehicle", function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (index, value) {
             $("#SelectedMakeId").append("<option value=" + value.MakeId + ">" + value.MakeName + "</option>");
        });
    });
});
```

Note that you have to give correct api method url. Instead of giving this url `http://localhost:2390/api/vehicle` you have to give your path.

***YOU CAN TRY THIS ONE ALSO***

You can use `ViewBag` as well. For that do the following,

**1. Set the route to api method `Makes()` as**

```
     [System.Web.Http.Route("api/Vehicle/MakersList")] 
     [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
     public IEnumerable<Make> Makes()
     {
        ...
     }
```

**2. Change the `Index` method**

Add the `GetMakers()` method that consume api method. Use this `GetMakers()` to initialize `ViewBag.listMakers`

```
     private string MAKER_URL = "http://localhost:2390/api/vehicle";
     public ActionResult Index()
     {
            ViewBag.listMakers = new SelectList(GetMakers(), "MakeId","MakeName");
            return View();
     }

     public IEnumerable<Make> GetMakers()
     {
       try
            {
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(MAKER_URL);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("vehicle/MakersList").Result;
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    return response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Make>>().Result;
                return null;
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }

     }
```

**3. Rewrite the `@Html.DropDownListFor` as**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedMakeId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.listMakers, "---Select---", new { @class = "makes_DDL" })
```

Comment: Oh thank you for the reply!! I was creating the second list similar to that but didn't think of just removing the Html.DropDownListFor completely and also using getJSON for the first list. Thank you, I will try it out!

Comment: Thank you once again! I will explore both options. The first one is working well for me! My getJSON had trouble firing because I thought I was supposed to follow the route URL in RouteConfig, instead of the URL in WebApiConfig. Once I used the address api/vehicle/makes instead of api/vehicle, it worked!