# Make json the default formatter in asp.net web api 2

Tags: asp.net-web-api

In my web api I allow the user to specify how they want their data via an extension: ie. host/api/location/getmyhouse.json or getmyhouse.xml.

However I also have actions that aren't get and they return if the action was successful or not. For that it doesn't really make sense to specify the return type so I was trying to have it just default to json. However by default it seems xml is used.

Is there a way to default the formatter to json vs xml without removing xml as a formatter AND without having the client specify it as I want this to be done via simple url in the browser. It's an internal thing so that's what we would like.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25224824/1260204

Comment: Possibly but no answer was selected. I'll try a few and see if any work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get ASP.NET Web API to return JSON instead of XML using Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847564/how-do-i-get-asp-net-web-api-to-return-json-instead-of-xml-using-chrome)